# Is the default value of FORCE_SSL_ADMIN documented?

Tags: redirect, ssl, documentation

*(**Update.** I rephrased the title since I understood better meanwhile what was going on.)*

Dealing with an attempt to understand HTTPS redirection, I ended up seeing with a massive `grep -r 'FORCE_SSL_ADMIN' ./www`, this piece of code in `default-constant.php` (Wordpress 5.7.2, line 328):

```
function wp_ssl_constants() {
    /**
     * @since 2.6.0
     */
    if ( ! defined( 'FORCE_SSL_ADMIN' ) ) {
        if ( 'https' === parse_url( get_option( 'siteurl' ), PHP_URL_SCHEME ) ) {
            define( 'FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true );
        } else {
            define( 'FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', false );
        }
    }
    /* [...] */
```

If I understand correctly, if the constant isn't set **and** the `siteurl` entry (apparently the URL site value set in Setting page of the dashboard) begins is of scheme `HTTPS://`, then `FORCE_SSL_ADMIN` is set to `true`.

Is this default behavior (redirection according to the site URL scheme) explained somewhere in the official documentation?

Comment: Not at first glance, no - [force_ssl_admin()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/force_ssl_admin/) links [here for FORCE_SSL_ADMIN](https://wordpress.org/support/article/administration-over-ssl/) but it's not spelled out there.

Comment: But I don't think this is surprising behaviour, is it? If we expect the site to be served over HTTPS then the admin pages should too, shouldn't they?

Comment: @Rup Yes, you may be right.